# Утечка памяти - потоки и серелизаторы (Thread и Serialize)

Tags: c#, serialize, многопоточность, memory

Имеется многопоточное приложение, использующее в потоках сериализаторы и десериализаторы, а так же очередт..

Потоки используются класса **Thread**, серелизаторы **DataContractJsonSerializer** (с методами *ReadObject* и *WriteObject* - с одним параметром, *Type*), а в качестве очереди используется **Queue**.

Периодически создаются объекты, которые добавляются в очередь для последующей обработке конвейерном ещё в одном потоке. Очередь обрабатывается быстро, быстрее чем в неё поступают данные.

В приложении имеется утечка памяти (*Working Set* растет за час примерно мегабайт на 10 - смотрю через **Process Explorer** *v15.22*, - а за пару суток набигает до 512 МБайт). Приложение использует десериализацию в 2-3 потоках каждые 5-15 секунд.

***Вопрос***: в какую сторону копать - искать утечку памяти в потоках или сериализаторах, или может даже в очереди (в последнем я очень сомневаюсь) ?

Comment: Попробуй 1 поток и 1 сериализатор, пускай работает с зацикленном режиме с небольшой паузой и обрабатывает очередь. Тогда меньше будет ошибок и все станет на свои места

Comment: Сериализатор один, просто он может использоваться разными потоками, которые создаются для синхронной обработки запросов от клиентов (поступают через TcpListener). Для сохранения запросов в БД используется очередь, которую разбирает и пишет в БД один поток.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Копать нужно только в одном направлении. Вот простая, но хорошая методика поиска утечек, которая скорее всего поможет:

1. подбираем методику, которая приводит к утечке памяти (в соответствии с TaskManager или по факту OutOfMemory). В Вашем случае это просто запустить и подождать часок-другой.
2. Скачиваем Memory analysis tool (тут зависит от желания - кто то может потратить штуку денег и купить крутой анализатор, а кто то может скачать простой, написанный на коленке). К примеру [этот](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) его 10 дней триала может хватить.  Либо [этот от МС с описанием](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/108529/LeakDiag-An-Effective-Memory-Leak-Analysis-Tool). Тут ещё гугл может очень помочь.
3. запустив программу под анализатором, смотрим результат. Обычно, если есть утечка, то каких то определенных объектов в памяти оказывается очень много. В некоторых случаях можно запускать несколько раз подряд с разной длительностью и смотреть на динамику. Если каких то объектов 1000, но кол-во не изменяется - может они просто кешируются. А течь может один объект в минуту, но на 10 мб. И даже через час их будет 60 штук.
4. вычислив объект(ы), количество которых растет, ищем в памяти их жизненный цикл, гуглим, спрашиваем о них на хэшкоде.

Поначалу будет казаться сложно - в дампе тысячи объектов. Но потом придет понимание и они не будут замечаться.

Comment: @avp по исчерпанию комментариев к ответу -- здесь. Такого я предлагать не хотел, но почему бы и нет? Природа утечек памяти в erlang сильно другая, так что, вероятно, проблема будет решена автоматически :)

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо провожу замеры, по результатом отпишусь - помогло или нет.

Answer (score 3):

У меня тоже была когда-то похожая проблема. Тоже приложение жрало всю отведенную память, затем, через несколько часов выдавало ошибку:

```
Out of Memory
```

После того, как я посмотрел состояние потоков приложения через монитор ресурсов, то я ахнул! Я допустил фатальную ошибку - не указывал при создании потока его автоудаление по завершению его работы. В итого "висело" порядка 300 ожидающих потоков в одном процессе! И это количество постоянно росло!

---

Быть может, вы просто создаете по одному новому потоку в таймере, например, но его потом не удаляете?

Comment: В `C#` это маловероятно, поскольку созданный `Thread` автоматически уничтожается после выполнения переданного ему делегата.

Comment: Да число потоков не увеличивается (конкретно в программе их число при тестах колеблется на 15-18, по сути большую часть времени работают 15 потоков, - как я понял, большая их часть создает .NET для своих нужд).

Comment: @t1nk, Microsoft не рекомендует создавать в одном процессе более 16 потоков. Это так, на будущее =)

Comment: @Asen 

http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.lang.functional/2005-11/msg00137.html

:))

Comment: @alexlz, а какая связь между процессами Erlang и потоками Windows?

IMHO комментарий не в тему.

Comment: @avp Оно конечно. В одном случае user-level threads, в другом -- уровня ядра. Но уж больно цифры различаются...

Comment: @alexlz, тут недавно обсуждали [реализацию процессов в erlang](http://hashcode.ru/questions/144673).

Так вот, реально процессов-потоков ОС немного. Erlang процессы моделируются на прикладном уровне. Просто по очереди циклически исполняются кусочки байт-кода запущенных erlang-процессов.

Comment: @avp круто

    -- Ты в баню?
    -- Да нет, я в баню.
    -- А я думал, что ты в баню.

Comment: @alexlz, признаю непонятно написал.

Несколько упрощенно - для ОС в erlang один процесс - это собственно интерпретатор байт-кода, а процессы в erlang программе это просто структуры данных, которые интерпретируются *синхронно* и о которых ОС ничего не знает.

Теперь понятно, что сравнивать некорректно?

Comment: @avp пошли теоретические изыскания. Я же не отрицал, что там потоки уровня пользователя. Только вот мне, как пользователю, какая разница, что там у потоков внутри. Ежели оно у викингов работает и не падает, а мелкомягкие советуют количество потоков ограничивать, то может мелкомягким следует что-то в консерватории подправить? (кстати, если мне не изменяет склероз, в виндах есть и user-level threads. Не говоря уж про erlang for windows)

Comment: @alexlz, IMHO разница в скорости и взаимодействии потоков с *реальной* системой. 

--

А вообще-то вопрос был про c# и поиск утечки памяти. Вы советуетет TC переписать его программу на erlang?